# how do I choose a row for my spritesheet animation?

Tags: processing

hello so I'm new to java / processing, and I'm trying to make this sprite sheet animated but what I have is this problem, I just can't figure it out, how to make my figure change between the number of rows the spritesheet has.

I've tried creating a variable so in order when you press certain keyCode it changes, but I don't know, if is it because, it's in function setup is not changing values or what.

```
int nx = 6;
int ny = 4;

int cs;
int ts = nx * ny;
int y = 0;
int dir = 0;

PImage[] sprites;

void setup()
{
  size(600,600);

  sprites = new PImage[ts];
  PImage spritesheet = loadImage("https://denysalmaral.com/wp- 
   content/uploads/2017/02/trump_run.png");

  int w = spritesheet.width / nx;
  int h = spritesheet.height / ny;

  int index = 0;

  move(index, w, h, sprites, spritesheet); 
}

void draw()
{
  background(0);

  ms();
  draw_sprite();
  frameRate(15);

}
void draw_sprite()
{
  pushMatrix();
  image(sprites[cs], 0, y,100,100);
  popMatrix();

}

void ms()
{
  cs += 1;
  cs %= ts;
}

void move(int index, int w, int h, PImage [] sprites, PImage spritesheet)
{ 

  for(int y = 0; y < ny; y++)
  {
    for(int x = 0; x < nx; x++)
    {
      sprites[index] = spritesheet.get(x * w, dir * h, w, h);

      index++;
    }
  }
}
```

I expect to change between the number of rows the spritesheet has but it just stays in dir = 0 
it doesn't change for example: dir = 2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this:

```
sprites[index] = spritesheet.get(x * w, dir * h, w, h);
```

to this:

```
sprites[index] = spritesheet.get(x * w, y * h, w, h);
```

to add all the rows to the spritesheet.

If you want to change the row based on what key was pressed, add this in void keyPressed():

```
switch(keyCode)
{
  case DOWN:
    dir = 0;
    break;
  case RIGHT:
    dir = 1;
    break;
  case UP:
    dir = 2;
    break;
  case LEFT:
    dir = 3;
    break;
}
```

and change

```
  image(sprites[cs], 0, y,100,100);
```

to

```
image(sprites[cs + dir * (ny + 2)], 0, y,100,100);
```

Edit: You have to also change

```
cs %= ts;
```

to

```
cs %= nx;
```

This is because if you don't, you will go through all rows, but you only want to go through one row at a time; the row gets changed in image().

Comment: hello, thanks for the help! I just have a quick questions. in image(sprites[cs + dir * (ny + 2)], 0, y,100,100);   if dir = 2 or more than two, it will go out of array bounds.

Comment: Yes, I am sorry, I forgot to add something.
In ms(), change cs %= ts; to cs %= nx;

That should solve it.

Comment: Also, please read [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)